# how to retrieve data from MongoDB database in node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

In node.js I am getting only partial data back.In the second object some data are missing.

The response:

```
{
'62d12069cb03235286511d5e': [
    {
      duration: [Object],
      isBookingCancelled: [Object],
      _id: new ObjectId("62d55611f4a5817f6b0441c6"),
      parkingId: new ObjectId("62d12069cb03235286511d5e"),
      user: new ObjectId("62c9511cc96c2b690028be91"),
      date: 2022-07-22T00:00:00.000Z,
      startTime: 2022-07-22T06:30:00.000Z,
      endTime: 2022-07-22T08:30:00.000Z,
      isFeePaid: false,
      status: 'sent',
      isStarted: false,
      isEnabled: false,
      createdAt: 2022-07-18T12:46:09.040Z,
      updatedAt: 2022-07-18T12:46:09.040Z,
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      duration: [Object],
      isEnabled: false,
      createdAt: 2022-07-18T12:49:49.921Z,
      updatedAt: 2022-07-18T12:49:49.921Z,
      __v: 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Sometime it gives full data but sometime it retrieves only partial data like above. Here is the query.

```
const bookings = await Booking.find({
      "isBookingCancelled.value": false,
      // parkingId: { $in: parkingIds },
    });

    let groupBookings = {};
    let tmppid = "";
    bookings.forEach((booking) => {
      tmppid = booking.parkingId.toString();
      if (typeof groupBookings[tmppid] === "undefined")
        groupBookings[tmppid] = [];
      groupBookings[tmppid].push(booking);
    });

    console.log(groupBookings);
```

Booking schema;
`ParkingId: ref: Parking, user: referenced to auth, date, startTime, duration: {days, hours, minutes}, endTime, isBookingcancelled, isFeePaid, isSatrted, isEnabled, paymentId refernced to Payment, and status`

Comment: @lpizzinidev question updated.

Comment: Can you also `console.log(bookings)`?

Comment: ```console.log(bookings)``` it works fine. It logs all the data of booking @HeikoTheißen